# Node.js: async-await and async npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

I have gone through [this](https://hackernoon.com/should-i-use-promises-or-async-await-126ab5c98789) tutorial. According to this [tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/should-i-use-promises-or-async-await-126ab5c98789), "Every time we use await, we are writing blocking code" In order to call multiple data, we can use separate async-await.

If in my program, I need to  to call multiple data.... I can use async-await multiple time or just the async(npm package) i.e async.parallel(). Sometime, I need to get single data, by that time.... I can use async-await. My question is:

In my project, can I use the both?

Comment: No, don't use the `async.js` package with promises. It uses callback-style, and they don't go well together.

Comment: "*Every time we use await, we are writing blocking code*" is just plain wrong. You are still writing asynchronous and therefore non-blocking code. All `await` does is running asynchronous (promise-returning) stuff *sequentially* in one function.

Comment: What do you mean by "*In order to call multiple data, we can use separate async-await / multiple time*"? Can you make an example where you would have used `async.parallel` that you cannot easily express with promises and `async`/`await`?

Comment: Here is the example: https://pastebin.com/tYq8xmpk

Comment: You'll want to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for that, e.g. `const [bookInstance, books] = await Promise.all([BookInstance.findById(req.params.id).populate('book'), Book.find()]);`

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Bergi, will that be a good choice, if we use something like that: https://pastebin.com/yvhj7W1P Please take a look on that pastebin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201775/discussion-between-tanjiya-and-bergi).

Comment: If you don't use `Promise.all` but have `await` twice, it will be sequential not concurrent. Might be fine though.